# Change default app launched when editing vector smart objects in Photoshop

Tags: file-association, adobe-creative-cloud

I installed the CC suite trial apps, however I haven't yet started the trials and prefer to continue with CS6 for the time being. However the installation changed the default editor for all my files to the CC versions. I've been able to change those back for most filetypes, however I'm not sure how to do this for vector smart objects being edited in Photoshop CS6. I want this to open AI CS6 but now it's trying to open AI CC which I don't want. 
I know the filetype is a "Vector PDF" but don't know if systemwide there is a way to specify that AI only open this particular type of PDF versus others.

Answer (score 0):

I installed winassociate.  Put a link in your sendto group.  Then you can set the association of any thing by sending it to winassoc and selecting a new program.

Alternately use open with option, and tell it to use this as the default.

Comment: That sounds Windows-y. I should have specified that I'm running OS X.

Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

To change the default app that opens when you open a file we can do the following:

1. Open Finder & locate the file type you wish to edit
2. Right Click & choose 'Get Info'
3. Expand the 'Open With' section by clicking the arrow
4. Click the drop down and choose the app you want to open the file with
5. Click the 'Change All' button to change all the files of this type

After we perform these steps the file will open with the app that we chose.